# Sails.js expireAfterSeconds option in the model

Tags: mongodb, model, sails.js, database

I am using sails to write a simple model which should expire after a few hours, so I need something like

```
    createdAt: {
        type: 'Date',
        expires : 60,
        index: true
    }
```

But the "expireAfterSeconds" seems not working when I check my database (MongoDB), therefore I have to use

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

I wonder if it is possible to set the "expire" option in the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the sails-mongo source code that is responsible for handling the `index` attribute property[1], it seems that it does not take into account anything like an `expires` property. This makes sense though, because the sails.js waterline ORM does not support database-specific functionality like expiring index data in MongoDB.

However, waterline does provide access to the MongoDB native connection (which uses [node-mongodb-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native)) through the `Collection.native()` method[2]

Chances are, you only really need to make changes to the model's index once during the lifecycle of the Sails application, so the best place to do that would be in the `config/bootstrap.js` file. At this point in the sails.js lifecycle, all of the models have been instantiated, so you could do something like this to perform the necessary logic on your keys:

```
// config/bootstrap.js
exports.bootstrap = function (done) {

    YourModelName.native(function (err, collection) {
        // define index properties
        collection.ensureIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } );

        // be sure to call the bootstrap callback to indicate completion
        done();
    });
}
```

You could take this even further and write a utility that inspects the models that sails has loaded (they are available as keys in the global object `sails.models`) and, if they have an `expires` attribute, perform the necessary native functionality. This would also need to be done in the `config/bootstrap.js`.

If you have native functionality that needs to be done on a per-record basis, you can use the sails.js model lifecycle hooks[3] for that.

references:

- [1] https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/ad7ec276af3a0e823ee5075074788ca915328db2/lib/adapter.js#L112
- [2] https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/21#issuecomment-20765896
- [3] See the section titled "Lifecycle Callbacks" @ http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

Comment: Thanks! Really nice solution! Just one comment: A callback function is need to perform the `ensureIndex` operation, otherwise an error will raise " Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback"

Comment: @Chuan: ah okay. then it would be important to call the done() inside the callback passed to ensureIndex if you want to prevent the bootstrap from continuing until the index has been ensured.

Comment: In my case it is save to let bootstrap continue, so I just put done() outside. But you're right, for some cases it is important to prevent it from continuing, good point!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
I created a sails hook to give advanced indexing options for models that use the sails-mongo adapter.

Supports all mongo indexing options.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-mongoat

---

OLD:

I created the below to do this automatically if the model attribute has an expires property and is of type 'date'. Just paste into to your config/bootstrap.js

Hope it helps!

```js
  _.forEach(Object.keys(sails.models), function(key) {
    var model = sails.models[key];
    _.forEach(Object.keys(model.attributes), function(attr) {
      if (model.attributes[attr].hasOwnProperty('expires')) {
        var seconds = model.attributes[attr].expires;
        // delete validators from global model, otherwise sails will error
        delete sails.models[key].attributes[attr].expires;
        delete sails.models[key]._validator.validations[attr].expires;
        if (model.attributes[attr].hasOwnProperty('type') && model.attributes[attr].type === 'date') {
          var obj = {};
          obj[attr] = 1;
          model.native(function(err, collection) {
            // define index properties
            collection.ensureIndex(obj, {
              expireAfterSeconds: seconds
            }, function(err) {
              if (err)
                sails.log.error(err);
              else
                sails.log.info(key + " model attribute '" + attr + "' has been set to expire the document after " + seconds + " seconds.");
            });
          });
        } else {
          sails.log.warn(key + " model attribute '" + attr + "' is set to expire but is not of type 'date'. Skipping...");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```